# iOS 9.3 memory issue

Tags: swift, generics

First of all, everything works like a charm under 10.2, but I have to support old iPhone 4s ;(

I reckon that this is generic-related issue, but any ideas how to debug this mess are very appreciated.

**step1)** Modify value
[image: step1]

**step2)** Everything is ok, value(*done*) has been successfully updated. Going to update *another* value(defined as `public var key: T?`)
[image: step2]

**step3)** Something weird has happened :(
[image: step3]

Comment: You have stepped out of the function and the variable is no longer accessible. This is expected behaviour.

Comment: @Oskar, This is class member, not a stack variable, have a look on others — they are ok. This property looks corrupted in all other calls right after this point.

Comment: ok this could well be a lldb related issue -- where it just can't display variable XY - happens to me a lot actually -- anyway: what actually happens on iphone - crash?

Comment: Daji-Djan, yeah. EXC_BAD_ACCESS on next access to keyProperty.